# HTML aside tag behavior on window restore down

Tags: html, user-interface

Below is the HTML code

```
  <div class="body-content" id="content"></div>
         <%@ include file="common/aside.jsp"%>
   <%@ include file="common/footer.jsp"%>
```

I have a navigation menu bar, from where I load the json data through ajax call inside the *content* div shown above. The json data is nothing but the array of array of objects which is displayed in jquery datatable. Then I have an aside, where i show my application's archives on right side of the page.

Everything works perfectly for maximized browser window but as i restore down, my archive aside comes below the datatable which looks weird.

Is there any way I could get over this ? Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little tardy, but it sounds like the main data element (the one inside the content, to the left of the *aside*) has an explicitly set width... or doesn't for that matter. I would suggest that you set the width of the 2 elements (the *aside* and the main data container) in % to try to prevent pop-down. If you care further, you might also go something like *.body-content {min-width: X00px;}* to keep it from getting to narrow.